# normalization for mlp in R (mnist dataset)

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, mnist

I'm new to machine learning and deep learning, I'm dealing with mnist dataset with keras package, tensorflow package and recipe package to build a mlp model.

I just have a question regarding the normalization process when I did the preprocessing.
I first try to divide all numeric variable (which are the pixels) to 255 so every data point will fall into [0,1], and then I did the following

```
#load the data
    digit <- read_csv("digit_train.csv") %>%
      clean_names() %>% 
      mutate(label = factor(label)) %>%
      mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(./255))
#split the data
    set.seed(52)
    train_test_split<- initial_split(digit, prop = 0.7)
    train <- training(train_test_split)
    test  <- testing(train_test_split)
#create recipe and build model    
    digit_recipe_mlp <- recipe(label ~ ., train) %>%
      update_role(id, new_role = "id") 
    
    digit_mlp <- mlp(hidden_units = 120,
                     epochs = 10,
                     dropout = .13,
                     activation = "relu") %>%
      set_engine("keras") %>%
      set_mode("classification")
    
    digit_wf_mlp <- workflow() %>%
      add_recipe(digit_recipe_mlp) %>%
      add_model(digit_mlp) %>%
      fit(train)
```

It turns out my model has some overfitting problem, and the overall accuracy is just 97.5%, I'm thinking how can I improve that. Then I tried to use another way to normalize my data in the recipe process. I did step_normalize and step_range, however, both of them did not work, if I tried them the fitting results only return NAN though the model can run. I'm wondering why that happened.

[image: This pic is a good running process before I add step_normalize]

```
digit_recipe_mlp <- recipe(label ~ ., train) %>%
  update_role(id, new_role = "id") %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric())

digit_mlp <- mlp(hidden_units = 120,
                 epochs = 10,
                 dropout = .13,
                 activation = "relu") %>%
  set_engine("keras") %>%
  set_mode("classification")

digit_wf_mlp <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(digit_recipe_mlp) %>%
  add_model(digit_mlp) %>%
  fit(train)
```

[image: This is the pic after I add step_normalize, nothing returned]